How to add styles to Script of next js
I'm using MUi + Next js version 13.3.0.
I added a Tidio Script, but this doesn't look good, so I want to update the position.
The documentation says to add this:
<style>
 #tidio-chat-iframe { bottom: 50px !important; }
 @media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
 #tidio-chat-iframe { bottom: 50px !important;}
}
</style>

Of course this can't be added this way on next js. How could I add this styles?
I tried to create a file css and import this on _app.js, but it doesn't work.
I've tried to use this with inline styles, but it seems doesn't work.
<Script
      id="tidio-chat-iframe"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        "__html": `
        var iframe = document.getElementById("tidio-chat-iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; bottom: 150px !important; width: 300px; @media only screen and (max-width: 980px) { bottom: 150px !important; }");`,
      }}
      src="//code.tidio.co/123.js"
    />


Do you mind adding code examples of how you attempted to import the CSS file into _app.js? This is certainly possible, and Vercel's own examples do this. See the following example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env/pages/_app.js
